# CDI JSF Managed Bean with ParameterizedType

Tags: jsf, generics, java-ee-6, cdi

I created a `base` managed bean that receives a `ParameterizedType`. 
My managed beans use CDI (`@Named` instead of `@ManagedBean`).

- If I use the default scope, the following code works.
- If I use the scope `@ViewScoped` (javax.faces.* or omnifaces1.8.1), the following exception occurs:

  > java.lang.Class incompatible with java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType java.lang.ClassCastException
- If I use `@ManagedBean` with the default scope (or `@ViewScoped`) the same exception occurs.

My environment:

```
IBM Websphere 8.5.5.2
JSF 2.0 (Apache MyFaces) + omnifaces 1.8.1
CDI (Apache OpenWebBeans)
```

Has anyone experienced this problem? 
There is solution for this?

```
public abstract class BaseMB<T> {
    private Class<T> myClass;
    public BaseMB() {
        this.myClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
}


@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyMB extends BaseMB<MyClass> {
}
```

P.S. I use this same strategy in the persistence layer and everything works properly.

```
public abstract class BaseDAO<T> {
    private Class<T> myEntity;
    public BaseDAO() {
        this.myEntity = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
}

public class MyEntityDAO extends BaseDAO<MyEntity> {
}
```

Comment: @BalusC Yes. The only way that worked was with "@Named", with no scope specified.

Comment: If it helps, I've copy and past your code and it works with @ViewScope. I'm using Mojarra (JSF) 2.1.6 and Glassfish 3.1.2.